# How to Auto-reload webpage only if there is change on server?

Tags: jsp, tomcat, reload

How can I auto reload a webpage if there is a change in JSP on server. Thus I do not want my page to be reloaded every few seconds but whenever changed JSP is processed by Jasper on Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [push](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology) functionality, when there is a change in your data server will notify the browser which in turn will display the new data. This is not an easy task to do, fortunately there are several frameworks that can make your life easier. To get started make a google search about Comet programming (for example this [tutorial](http://www.webreference.com/programming/javascript/rg28/index.html))